# Program is not checking the second condition

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

When I run my game it works fine on the bottom portion of the object collision but, it will not distguish that one and the other if. It is not reading the second one. I took a picture and you can see the (x, y) coords and it meets the condition but, I can still move.

IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjcHB.png

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player{

int x = 1; // Location of player
int y = 314; // location of player
int xa = 0; // Representation of where the player goes
int ya = 0; // Representation of where the player goes
int playerWeight = 115;
private int speed = 2;
int[] playerPos = {x, y};
private static final int WIDTH = 30;
private static final int HEIGHT = 30;

private Game game;

public Player(Game game){
    this.game=game;
}

public void move(){
    System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
    x = x + xa;
    y = y + ya;

    if(x + xa < 0) // Left Bounds
        xa = 0;
    if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - WIDTH) // Right Bounds
        xa = 0;
    if (y + ya < 0) // Top Bounds
        ya = 0;
    if(y + ya > game.getHeight() - WIDTH)
        ya = 0;
    if (collision()) // Tile bounds
        y = y - 4;
    if (collision2()){

        if(x > 370 && x < 531 && y < 286){ // Check for 3 values 
            y = y + 4; 
            System.out.println("-x");
            /*
             * Use the gravity() method to determine player fall rate
             */
        }

        else if(x > 370 && x < 531 && y > 223){ // Check for 3 values 
            ya = 0;
            System.out.println("+x");
            /*
             * Use the gravity() method to determine player fall rate
             */
        }

    }
}

// Method to find where player is located
public int[] Playerposition(){
    x = 1;
    y = 300;
    return playerPos;
}

public void Gravity(){


}

public void paint(Graphics2D g2d){
    //Draws player to screen
    g2d.drawImage(getPlayerImg(), x, y, null);
}

public Image getPlayerImg(){
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/AncientPandas/Desktop/KingsQuest/Misc/Images/Sprites/player.png");
    return ic.getImage();
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    xa = 0;
    ya = 0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S)
        xa = -speed;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F)
        xa = speed;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_E)
        ya = -speed;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D)
        ya = speed;
}

public Rectangle getBoundsPlayer(){
    return new Rectangle(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

private boolean collision(){
    return game.maplayout.getBoundsBlock().intersects(getBoundsPlayer());
}

private boolean collision2(){
    return game.maplayout.getBoundsBlock2().intersects(getBoundsPlayer());
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
    else if(x > 370 && x < 531 && y > 223){ // Check for 3 values 
        ya = 0;
        System.out.println("+x");
        /*
         * Use the gravity() method to determine player fall rate
         */
    }
```

to:

```
    if(x > 370 && x < 531 && y < 286){ // Check for 3 values 
        y = y + 4; 
        System.out.println("-x");
        /*
         * Use the gravity() method to determine player fall rate
         */
    }

    if(x > 370 && x < 531 && y > 223){ // Check for 3 values 
        ya = 0;
        System.out.println("+x");
        /*
         * Use the gravity() method to determine player fall rate
         */
    }
```

Reason being is that the keyword "else" will only execute code within it's block if the above "if" statement's condition fails/requirements are not met. For example:

```
boolean anInteger = 9;
if (anInteger == 1999) {
    // ...
} else {
    // If 'anInteger' is not equal to 9, then execute the following code (within this block)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I fixed by adding a 4th location check for y position because my previous y was conflicting with the other.